# Build C# project from dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I can view C# code from .NET ddl's with ILSpy. Are there any programs to build completed C# project from the dll?

P.S. I don't want to include dll to my existing project. I want to grab some code from dll and understand how it works. But it is harder to read code directly from reflector. I prefer to read code from Visual Studio and want to create "Class Library" project from dll.

Comment: you can add the dll as an assembly and call all the functions if that is what you are asking...

Comment: It's already built and therefore in a dll. As soandos says, you can reference the dll and access all it's functions. I don't know what you think you can achieve by recompiling the decompiled code...

Comment: Well the question is asking how to get the C# project back from an already compiled code.  I assume because he wants to make changes to it, not just use it...

Comment: @Andy - that would make more sense, just couldn't work out his intentions from the description.

Comment: The DLL has *already* been built. You can use it just like it is. Why do you want to build it *again*? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question right, You can create a complete project file including the code from a dll using Redgate's .Net Reflector

```
http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1
```

There are other free products in the market including Telerik's JustDecompile I am not very sure about it!!

```
http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx
```

Having said that, Redgate's .Net Reflector works fine when the DLL contains code which are fairly straight foreword, I did find it buggy when the DLL are referencing many other DLLs.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for Reflector, which can decompile DLLs to complete C# projects.